# Access text field of another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to access a text field from another class.

I'm developing a Mac application. My main window is defined in `MainMenu.xib`, which is controlled by an `AppDelegate` class. In my window I have a text field, `tbxTest`. In `AppDelegate.h` this is defined as:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *tbxTest;
```

In `AppDelegate.m`:

```
@synthesize tbxTest;
```

Now, let's say my other window is controlled by `MyWindowController` ( : `NSWindowController`). In this window I have a button. The method to be called when clicking this button is `btnClose`.

In `MyWindowController.h`:

```
- (IBAction)btnClose:(id)sender;
```

In `MyWindowController.m`:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
...
- (IBAction)btnClose:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [AppDelegate alloc];
    NSString *test = appDelegate.tbxArtist.stringValue;
    if (test != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"test is%@", test);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"test is nil");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `test` *is always* `nil`.

How can I do this? I bet it has something to do with this line: `AppDelegate *appDelegate = [AppDelegate alloc];`, but I haven't been able to find any information on Google about it. I don't want to `init` it, because there's only one instance of the main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alloc` is a class method that allocates memory for an object. You have therefore allocated the memory for a new delegate, which is not what you want.

Reaching for your app delegate all the time is a bad pattern to follow but to get a reference to your delegate you would need to update your code to this.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (id)[NSApplication sharedInstance].delegate;
NSString *test = appDelegate.tbxArtist.stringValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. You're saying it's a bad pattern. May I ask how you would do it instead?

Comment: Well in this case `tbxArtist` has no business being an ivar of the app delegate. It would make more sense to be an ivar on your window subclass, which you would then access with `self.tbxArtist.stringValue`